# Boolean addition in Javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean-logic

How do i do a clean boolean add in javascript?

```
1+1 = 0;
1+0 = 1;
1+1+1 = 1;
```

etc. can one just sum booleans?

```
true+true = false
false+true = true;
```

etc.

Comment: Isn't `1+1` supposed to be 1 in boolean addition?

Comment: @basilikum No. `0 + 0 = 0`, `0 + 1 = 1`, `1 + 0 = 1` and `1 + 1 = 0 (with a carry over of 1)`. Hence boolean addition is the xor operator and the carry can be found using boolean multiplication (i.e. the and operator).

Comment: @AaditMShah Hmm...ok, but then why does every source I find say that boolean addition is equivalent to OR and that `1+1` equals `1`.

Comment: @basilikum Because boolean multiplication is `and` and boolean addition is in fact `or`. However I believe that the OP is looking to create a half adder. This requires the xor operation.

Comment: OR is obviously OR whilst + is something else. (The carry part mentioned above etc. Yes half-adder)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [bitwise XOR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.5E_%28Bitwise_XOR%29):

```
1 ^ 1 = 0
1 ^ 0 = 1
1 ^ 1 ^ 1 = 1
```

**FWIW:** The same works for most high-level programming languages.

Comment: This is not the same as boolean addition. Boolean addition is the xor operator.

Comment: @AaditMShah I think the equivalent to a boolean addition really is the OR operator. Look at this for example: http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_7/2.html

Comment: @basilikum I understand what you're trying to say but I believe that the OP is looking to create an adder in JavaScript. Hence the sum is found using xor and the carry is found using and. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)

Comment: @VisioN yes that's right. But OR still seems to be equivalent to a boolean addition. Just google "boolean addition". However, if OP really wants `1+1` to be equal to `0`, than he probably doesn't really look for a boolean addition, since this would give `1` as a result.

Comment: I actually ended up doing just (bool1+bool2+bool3)%2

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is the [xor operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_XOR%29):

```
1 ^ 1 = 0;
1 ^ 0 = 1;
1 ^ 1 ^ 1 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1 ^ 1 = 0;
1 ^ 0 = 1;
```

for boolean this can be achieved by using Short-circuit AND and OR operators.

```
function myXOR(a,b) {   
       return ( a || b ) && !( a && b );    
}
myXOR(true,true) == false
```

Answer (score 0):

you can code yor for bool like this:

```
function xor(a,b) {
  if (a === true && b === true) {
     return false;
   }
 return a || b;   
}
```

OR in typescript:

```
   xor(a: boolean,b: boolean): boolean {
     if (a === true && b === true) {
       return false;
     }
     return a || b;
  }
```